# Fibonnaci sequence explanation

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me some parts of this code:

```
public static void sequence(int nterms){ 
     int num1 = 0; 
     int num2 = 1; 
     int num = 2;  

     if (nterms <= 0){ 
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer"); 

     } 
     else if (nterms == 1){ 
      System.out.println(" fibonacci sequence: " + num1);
     }
     else{ 
      System.out.println(num1 ); 
      System.out.println(num2);

      while (num < nterms){ 
       int nth = num1 + num2; 
       System.out.println(nth); 
       num1 = num2;  
       num2 = nth; 
       num++;
      }
     }
    }
```

The number sequence that's in the output is correct. So the code works. But why do you do num++ in the end? I know nth is previous two numbers added together but why do you nterms == 1 and print "" +num1? I don't get that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's some code, please explain it to me" are considered off-topic here.

Comment: So, what happens if you omit the `num++;` at the end?  And why?

Comment: "why do you nterms == 1 and print "" +num1?" If there's only one number then that's all you need to print. `Else` it will go through `n` terms to complete the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
 public static void sequence(int nterms){ 
     /*instancation of needed variables : nth = num1+numb2 later in the code*/
     int num1 = 0; 
     int num2 = 1; 
     /*num is the number of term you've encoutered, as the first two are in
     the initialization, you start at 2*/
     int num = 2;  

     if (nterms <= 0){ //check wether the function has a correct input or not*/
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer"); 

     } 
     else if (nterms == 1){ /*if it's the first term we know in num1*/
      System.out.println(" fibonacci sequence: " + num1);
     }
     else{ 
      System.out.println(num1);/*we print the first two terms*/ 
      System.out.println(num2);

      while (num < nterms){ /*we loop till we reached the wanted number*/
       /*we know a term is equal to the two terms before it, at least I hope you do*/
       int nth = num1 + num2; 
       System.out.println(nth); /*we've got our number so we print it*/
       num1 = num2;  /*we make sure num1 and num2 are the last two encountered, so num1 becomre num2 and num2 become the current term (nth)*/
       num2 = nth; 
       num++;/*we increment the variable as we've met printed a new term*/
      }
     }
    }
```